# R - Save output of a loop in each iteration

Tags: r

I am doing a stepwise matching of two data sets based on different unique identifiers. I want to store the number of rows matched and unmatched in each step (iteration). Since the process is very repetitive I think that could be done with a loop buy I haven't been able to do it (still a beginner). This is the current (not very elegant) code:

```
# Data

dput(a)
structure(list(V1 = c("96099", "14072", "177877", "192619", "3554", 
"181507", "76016", "192123"), WAPC_gz = c("04LODGEAVENUERM82JA", 
"06RIVERROADIG110EY", "07SPRINGPONDROADRM95DP", "09DAGENHAMAVENUERM96LD", 
"09SKIPPERCOURTABBEYROADIG117GW", "1-11VINERIESCLOSERM95DA", 
"1-2MORLANDROADRM109HW", "10-11THEVINERIESVINERIESCLOSERM95DA"
), WAWPC_gz = c("04LODGEAVENUE", "06RIVERROAD", "07SPRINGPONDROAD", 
"09DAGENHAMAVENUE", "09SKIPPERCOURTABBEYROAD", "1-11VINERIESCLOSE", 
"1-2MORLANDROAD", "10-11THEVINERIESVINERIESCLOSE"), T8PC_gz = c("04LODGERM82JA", 
"06RIVERIG110EY", "07SPRINRM95DP", "09DAGENRM96LD", "09SKIPPIG117GW", 
"1-11VINRM95DA", "1-2MORLRM109HW", "10-11THRM95DA"), T8_FPC_gz = c("04LODGERM82JA", 
"06RIVERIG110EY", "07SPRINRM95DP", "09DAGENRM96LD", "09SKIPPIG117GW", 
"1-11VINRM95DA", "1-2MORLRM109HW", "10-11THRM95DA"), PPNPC_gz = c("04RM82JA", 
"06IG110EY", "07RM95DP", "09RM96LD", "09IG117GW", "111RM95DA", 
"12RM109HW", "1011RM95DA"), adr_gz = c(" 04 LODGE AVENUE RM82JA", 
" 06 RIVER ROAD IG110EY", " 07 SPRINGPOND ROAD RM95DP", " 09 DAGENHAM AVENUE RM96LD", 
"09 SKIPPER COURT ABBEY ROAD IG117GW", " 1-11 VINERIES CLOSE RM95DA", 
" 1-2 MORLAND ROAD RM109HW", "10-11 THE VINERIES VINERIES CLOSE RM95DA"
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001f0788>, .Names = c("V1", 
 "WAPC_gz", "WAWPC_gz", "T8PC_gz", "T8_FPC_gz", "PPNPC_gz", "adr_gz"
 ))

dput(b)
structure(list(V1 = c("192619", "3554", "181507", "76016", "192123", 
"121768", "8355", "124567"), WAPC_gp = c("09DAGENHAMAVENUERM96LD", 
"09SKIPPERCOURTABBEYROADIG117GW", "1-11VINERIESCLOSERM95DA", 
"1-2MORLANDROADRM109HW", "10-11THEVINERIESVINERIESCLOSERM95DA", 
"1000GREENLANERM81BT", "1001LEMONADEBUILDING3ARBORETUMPLACEIG117PY", 
"1002GREENLANERM81BT"), WAWPC_gp = c("09DAGENHAMAVENUE", "09SKIPPERCOURTABBEYROAD", 
"1-11VINERIESCLOSE", "1-2MORLANDROAD", "10-11THEVINERIESVINERIESCLOSE", 
"1000GREENLANE", "1001LEMONADEBUILDING3ARBORETUMPLACE", "1002GREENLANE"
 ), T8PC_gp = c("09DAGENRM96LD", "09SKIPPIG117GW", "1-11VINRM95DA", 
 "1-2MORLRM109HW", "10-11THRM95DA", "1000GRERM81BT", "1001LEMIG117PY", 
"1002GRERM81BT"), T8_FPC_gp = c("09DAGENRM96LD", "09SKIPPIG117GW", 
"1-11VINRM95DA", "1-2MORLRM109HW", "10-11THRM95DA", "1000GRERM81BT", 
 "1001LEMIG117PY", "1002GRERM81BT"), PPNPC_gp = c("09RM96LD", 
"09IG117GW", "111RM95DA", "12RM109HW", "1011RM95DA", "1000RM81BT", 
"10013IG117PY", "1002RM81BT"), adr_gp = c(" 09 DAGENHAM AVENUE RM96LD", 
"09 SKIPPER COURT ABBEY ROAD IG117GW", " 1-11 VINERIES CLOSE RM95DA", 
" 1-2 MORLAND ROAD RM109HW", "10-11 THE VINERIES VINERIES CLOSE RM95DA", 
" 1000 GREEN LANE RM81BT", "1001 LEMONADE BUILDING 3 ARBORETUM PLACE IG117PY", 
" 1002 GREEN LANE RM81BT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001f0788>, .Names = c("V1", 
"WAPC_gp", "WAWPC_gp", "T8PC_gp", "T8_FPC_gp", "PPNPC_gp", "adr_gp"
))
```

## FUNCTION

```
## Steps order (these are the columns containing unique identifiers)
step1<-2
step2<-4
step3<-5
step4<-6
step5<-3

steps<-(c(2,4,5,6,3))
matching <- function (a,b) {

first_join<-merge(b,a,by.y=names(a)[step1], by.x=names(b)[step1], all.x =   TRUE)
unmatch_1<- first_join %>% filter(is.na(adr_gz)) %>% select(1:length(names(b)))
match_1<- first_join %>% filter(!is.na(adr_gz)) %>%
select(grep("adr|UPRN|id|V1.x",names(first_join)))

second_join<-merge(unmatch_1,a,by.y=names(a)[step2], by.x=names(b)[step2], all.x = TRUE)
unmatch_2<- second_join %>% filter(is.na(adr_gz)) %>% select(1:length(names(b)))
match_2<- second_join %>% filter(!is.na(adr_gz)) %>%
select(grep("adr|UPRN|id|V1.x",names(first_join)))

third_join<-merge(unmatch_2,a,by.y=names(a)[step3], by.x=names(b)[step3], all.x = TRUE)
unmatch_3<- third_join %>% filter(is.na(adr_gz)) %>% select(1:length(names(b)))
match_3<- third_join %>% filter(!is.na(adr_gz)) %>%
select(grep("adr|UPRN|id|V1.x",names(first_join)))

fourth_join<-merge(unmatch_3,a,by.y=names(a)[step4], by.x=names(b)[step4], all.x = TRUE)
unmatch_4<- fourth_join %>% filter(is.na(adr_gz)) %>% select(1:length(names(b)))
match_4<- fourth_join %>% filter(!is.na(adr_gz)) %>%
select(grep("adr|UPRN|id|V1.x",names(first_join)))

fifth_join<-merge(unmatch_4,a,by.y=names(a)[step5], by.x=names(b)[step5], all.x = TRUE)
unmatch_5<- fifth_join %>% filter(is.na(adr_gz)) %>% select(1:length(names(b)))
match_5<- fifth_join %>% filter(!is.na(adr_gz)) %>%
select(grep("adr|UPRN|id|V1.x",names(first_join)))

matches<-c((nrow(match_1)),(nrow(match_2)),(nrow(match_3)),
           (nrow(match_4)),(nrow(match_5)))
unmatches<-c((nrow(unmatch_1)),(nrow(unmatch_2)),(nrow(unmatch_3)),
           (nrow(unmatch_4)),(nrow(unmatch_5)))
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(names(a)[steps],matches,unmatches))
print(df)
  }
```

I think the code could be simpler by doing a loop looking like that I guess:

```
`steps<-(c(2,4,5,6,3))

matching2 <- function (a,b) {

join<-NULL
unmatch<-NULL
match<-NULL
result<-NULL
match_row<- NULL

    for(i in 1:length(steps))

join<-merge(b,a,by.y=names(a)[steps[i]], by.x=names(b)[steps[i]], all.x = TRUE)
  unmatch<- join %>% filter(is.na(adr_gz)) %>% select(1:length(names(b)))
  match<- join %>% filter(!is.na(adr_gz)) %>%
  select(grep("adr|UPRN|id|V1.x",names(first_join)))

  match_row<-nrow(match)

  result= rbind(match_row,result)
  print(result)
```

}

Any comment/recommendation will be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Without reproducible data there isn't much that anyone can help with. Can you edit and use `dput` to give the data we're talking about?

Comment: @Carl Boneri, sorry about not providing enough information. I've just edited the question adding some dummy data with the `dput` function. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for providing data. I think I'm missing the overall goal though? could you maybe put your goal in different terms?

Comment: Of course @Carl Boneri. Basically, the two data sets are joined first based on a specific unique identifier. The output are subsets of "matched" and "unmatched" cases. Then in the second step, the "unmatched" are again join with the other data set, but based on a second unique identifier. The process continues with different unique identifiers. So the goal is to store in each iteration both the "unmatched" and the "matched" cases associated with the joins in each step. At the end, I will produce a table with the number of cases matched and un matched with each unique identifiers.